# JNI - Cannot find native library

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a JNI wrapper for a C++ native library. When I try to load the library in my Java code, I see the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Foo in java.library.path
```

I load the library like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("Foo");
```

I set java.library.path as follow:

```
java.library.path = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib
```

I added `-XshowSettings:properties` to the JVM options and confirmed that the java.library.path is set as shown above.

Here's the library .so on the filesystem:

```
$ l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libFoo.so 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   448K 29 Oct 14:23 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libFoo.so
```

Environment information:

```
java.version = 1.7.0_40
os.arch = x86_64
os.name = Mac OS X
os.version = 10.10
```

So why can't I load the library?

Comment: What do you get if instead you call `System.load("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libFoo.so")`?

Comment: Hmm. It seems to load it fine with a full path like that. I wonder why it doesn't work through `java.library.path`.

Comment: Let's see, I think on Mac OS X, it won't look for files ending with `.so`, only for those ending with `.dylib`.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be the issue. If I rename the .so to .dylib, it finds it. Now I just need to compile the library into .dylib, but that answers this question. If you add it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X, the JDK will not search the path for files ending in `.so`, or anything else than `.dylib` or `.jnilib`. We need to make sure filenames of native libraries end with `.dylib` or `.jnilib`.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/05-CoreJavaAPIs/CoreJavaAPIs.html

Answer (score 1):

Place your .so files in jni/libs folder. If you have the library for multiple platforms, you need to create a folder for each platform and place the corresponding file. For example jni/libs/x86 will have the .so file built for x86 platforms. If you are using Android Studio, it is slightly different than this.

Comment: I moved it to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jni/libs` and updated java.library.path, but I still get the same problem. Not using Android.